# Como remover a primeira chave que envolve todos os valores de um JSON

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Gente é possível remover a primeira chave `{ }` de um JSON e adicionar em linhas abaixo (Enter), de cada valor?

```js
var obj = {
  "arvore": "/",
  "avo": "obadias",
  "pai": {
    "eu": "Leonardo"
  }
}

class Access {
  static getRaiz(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = Access.getRaiz(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu percebi corretamente, está a tentar formatar visualmente o objeto que saiu de um JSON.

Para a formatação que quer pode:

- Chamar o [`Stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) com um espaçamento especifico
- Cortar o primeiro e ultimo caratere com `slice(1,-1)`
- Utilizar a etiqueta `<pre>` para manter a formatação no html

Exemplo:

```js
var obj = {
  "arvore": "/",
  "avo": "obadias",
  "pai": {
    "eu": "Leonardo"
  }
}

class Access {
  static getRaiz(obj) {
    //4 é o numero de espaços que cada objeto anda para dentro
    return JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4); 
  }
}

//aqui utiliza o <pre> no inicio e o slice para cortar primeiro e ultimo
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + Access.getRaiz(obj).slice(1,-1) + '</pre>';
```

Com [interpolação de Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) podia fazer a construção do html da seguinte forma:

```
document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${Access.getRaiz(obj).slice(1,-1)}</pre>`;
```

Esta segunda forma acaba por simplificar bastante quando tem de incluir muitas expressões numa String.